# Deleting/Creating Assets from contributor or via REST doesn't always trigger Lucene indexing or Delete them?

Tags: lucene, webcenter-sites

I have assets that are indexed as by name and parentname, name toknized false and stored true, parentname toknized is false and stored is false too.

On deleting one of these assets (created via REST or from contributor) via REST or from contributor, it doesn't always get deleted even if I get asset deleted message, it still shows in the contributor search, not in content tree or via Lucien search API, can't edit or redelete them ?

On Creating assets via REST, they don't all get indexed, they all are shown in the content tree but not in  the contributor search or retrieved by Lucien search API, they are indexed on editing them and start appearing in results ?

How can these two issues be fixed ?

**EDIT**
Tried Luke and the index files are intact not corrupted, as expected the missing asst IDs aren't in it and the deleted asset ID's were there.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like fairly typical lucene behavior when changes (insertion, deletion) are made on the index, but a new reader has not yet been opened for searching.  No changes will be available until the reader has been reopened.

According to the [webcenter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29636/asset_type_search.htm):

> Once the index is built, the Lucene search engine runs an event every thirty seconds that checks for changes made to assets of the types selected for indexing. If changes were made (such as creating a new index item, editing an existing entry, or deleting an entry) Lucene updates the index automatically.

If you are finding that you aren't seeing updates become searchable in the interface after waiting 30 sec, you may have some misconfiguration preventing it.  I noticed a note in the same documentation, indicating that the search indexing may be stops, allowing searching to continue, but preventing any updates from being made available to the interface:

> If you stop Global search indexing, the search index used for the Contributor interface search function and the public site will not be updated. Therefore, search results will not be accurate.

Answer (score -1):

If you have siteExplore installed with WCS you can add the index to the Global_q using siteExplore 
please add

Log into Editorial Sites Explorer and add a record to the Global_Q table for this asset with the following values

- id: any number (When you save the record a unique id will be generated.)
- assettype: the asset type of the asset found in excel sheet
- assetid: the id of the asset found in excel sheet
- action: U (U stands for Update the index for this asset)
- save All